# Copy dockerfile files ADD instruction in superset

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-superset

I have the following DockerFile

```
FROM apache/superset:pr-19860
RUN pip install elasticsearch-dbapi
RUN superset superset fab create-admin \
               --username admin \
               --firstname Superset \
               --lastname Admin \
               --email admin@superset.com \
               --password admin

RUN superset superset db upgrade
RUN superset superset load_examples
RUN superset superset init
ADD https://github.com/domsoltel/superset/blob/436efe104938d0ca555bb99c586f3d2675a69a59/config.py /app/superset/
ADD https://github.com/domsoltel/superset/blob/436efe104938d0ca555bb99c586f3d2675a69a59/viz.py /app//superset/
```

I have to modify the `config.py` and `viz.py` file to make it work the way I want it to.  These files already exist in the superset container but I need to modify a few variables

If I do `docker cp` it works perfectly, from my pc to the container it works perfectly but with the dockerfile I get the following error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/superset/config.py'

I think it might be a permissions problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by ...but with the dockerfile....  ?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I mean how can I grant permissions on my dockerfile (I am using docker-destop on Windows) but I run it on a linux terminal (ubuntu). 

If I stop the container and do:

`docker cp /home/config.py superset:/app/superset.config.py`

It works fine. But I want to automate that and not do it all the time, I want it to be done when I do the `docker-compose up`

Comment: It's not a good solution, no idea why ADD isn't working for you. But you can as an alternative try: 

RUN npm install -g github-files-fetcher 
RUN fetcher --url='{your url}' --out='/app/superset/config.py'

Comment: I have this error:
`> > [6/8] RUN npm install -g github-files-fetcher:
#0 0.299 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
>------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install -g github-files-fetcher]: >exit code: 127`

Comment: One thing is that you're ADDing HTML versions of the files which isn't going to work. You should use the raw versions, like this one https://raw.githubusercontent.com/domsoltel/superset/436efe104938d0ca555bb99c586f3d2675a69a59/config.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The superset image is set up to run as the user `superset` which doesn't have full permissions. So before your change anything, you should switch to `root` and then back to the `superset` user when you´re done.

You can see an example at the bottom of the page for the image (under 'How to extend this image'): https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset

```
FROM apache/superset:pr-19860
USER root
RUN pip install elasticsearch-dbapi
RUN superset superset fab create-admin \
               --username admin \
               --firstname Superset \
               --lastname Admin \
               --email admin@superset.com \
               --password admin

RUN superset superset db upgrade
RUN superset superset load_examples
RUN superset superset init
ADD --chown=superset:superset https://raw.githubusercontent.com/domsoltel/superset/436efe104938d0ca555bb99c586f3d2675a69a59/config.py /app/superset/
ADD --chown=superset:superset https://raw.githubusercontent.com/domsoltel/superset/436efe104938d0ca555bb99c586f3d2675a69a59/viz.py /app/superset/
RUN chmod 644 /app/superset/config.py && chmod 644 /app/superset/viz.py
USER superset
```

I've also changed the URLs of the files to the raw versions. With the URLs you had, you would add HTML versions of the files which isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you Hans, bet I get this eror another time:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/superset/config.py'`

Comment: I don't know what the problem is because with the COPY instruction of the dockerfile it works and doesn't give me any error problems, but the files are in Github

Comment: That's strange. When I build it using the above Dockerfile, it builds with no errors. Do you get the error at build time or at run time?

Comment: @DomRl It looks like the 2 .py files need to be owned by the `superset` user, so I've added `--chown` to the ADD statements. I've also set the permissions on them, so they have the same permissions as the other files in the `/app/superset/` directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `docker-compose`; then use volumes to map those files

```yaml
you_service:
  image: .....
  ....
  ....
  volumes:
    - /home/config.py:/app/superset/config.py
    - /home/viz.py:/app/superset/viz.py
```

Note that volumes **must** be an absolute path to work with mapping files (unlike mapping directories)

Another note: if the file is in-use by the container; then you'll get the permission error anyway!

Comment: I moved the files to the folder where I have the .yml and the dockerfile and with the instruction `COPY ./config.py /app/superset/config.py` it worked.

My idea is not to have the files locally, but to get the files from github. The `ADD instruction` gives me permissions error, what can I do?